# Recursive function calculating factorials leads to stack overflow

Tags: rust, biginteger, factorial, bignum

I tried a recursive factorial algorithm in Rust. I use this version of the compiler:

```
rustc 1.12.0 (3191fbae9 2016-09-23)
cargo 0.13.0-nightly (109cb7c 2016-08-19)
```

**Code:**

```
extern crate num_bigint;
extern crate num_traits;

use num_bigint::{BigUint, ToBigUint};
use num_traits::One;

fn factorial(num: u64) -> BigUint {
    let current: BigUint = num.to_biguint().unwrap();
    if num <= 1 {
        return One::one();
    }
    return current * factorial(num - 1);
}

fn main() {
    let num: u64 = 100000;
    println!("Factorial {}! = {}", num, factorial(num))
}
```

I got this error:

```
$ cargo run

thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
error: Process didn't exit successfully
```

How to fix that? And why do I see this error when using Rust?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Rust doesn't have tail call elimination, so your recursion is limited by your stack size. It may be a feature for Rust in the future (you can read more about it at the [Rust FAQ](https://prev.rust-lang.org/en-US/faq.html#does-rust-do-tail-call-optimization)), but in the meantime you will have to either not recurse so deep or use loops.

Comment: Great answer! But there are another problem with loop for factorial bigint - extremly slow.

Comment: @mrLSD I don't doubt it! But recursion, at least in Rust, doesn't really offer any speed improvements over loops. At least I haven't heard of that.

Comment: @mrLSD Although LLVM *can* optimize certain tail calls, the function in the question does not have a tail call and would not be optimized anyway, even in a language that guaranteed TCO

Answer (score 15):

#### Why?

This is a stack overflow which occurs whenever there is no stack memory left. For example, stack memory is used by

- local variables
- function arguments
- return values

Recursion uses a lot of stack memory, because for every recursive call, the memory for all local variables, function arguments, ... has to be allocated on the stack.

---

> #### How to fix that?

The obvious solution is to write your algorithm in a non-recursive manner (you should do this when you want to use the algorithm in production!). But you can also just **increase the stack size**. While the stack size of the main thread *can't* be modified, you can create a new thread and set a specific stack size:

```
fn main() {
    let num: u64 = 100_000;
    // Size of one stack frame for `factorial()` was measured experimentally
    thread::Builder::new().stack_size(num as usize * 0xFF).spawn(move || {
        println!("Factorial {}! = {}", num, factorial(num));
    }).unwrap().join();
}
```

This code **works** and, when executed via `cargo run --release` (with optimization!), outputs the solution after only a couple of seconds calculation.

---

#### Measuring stack frame size

In case you want to know how the stack frame size (memory requirement for *one* call) for `factorial()` was measured: I printed the address of the function argument `num` on each `factorial()` call:

```
fn factorial(num: u64) -> BigUint {
    println!("{:p}", &num);
    // ...
}
```

The difference between two successive call's addresses is (more or less) the stack frame size. On my machine, the difference was slightly less than `0xFF` (255), so I just used that as size.

In case you're wondering why the stack frame size isn't smaller: the Rust compiler doesn't really optimize for this metric. Usually it's really not important, so optimizers tend to sacrifice this memory requirement for better execution speed. I took a look at the assembly and in this case many `BigUint` methods were inlined. This means that the local variables of other functions are using stack space as well!

Comment: Note: much like that famous cat, measuring stack frame size may increase it (before the address of `num` was taken, it could leave in a register, and `println!` requires some stack space too).

Answer (score 7):

Just as an alternative.. (I do not recommend)

Matts answer is true to an extent. There is a crate called `stacker` ([here](https://crates.io/crates/stacker/)) that can artificially increase the stack size for usage in recursive algorithms. It does this by allocating some heap memory to overflow into.

As a word of warning... this takes *a very long time to run* ... but, it runs, and it doesn't blow the stack. Compiling with optimizations brings it down but its still pretty slow. You're likely to get better perf from a loop as Matt suggests. I thought I would throw this out there anyway.

```
extern crate num_bigint;
extern crate num_traits;
extern crate stacker;

use num_bigint::{BigUint, ToBigUint};
use num_traits::One;

fn factorial(num: u64) -> BigUint {
    // println!("Called with: {}", num);
    let current: BigUint = num.to_biguint().unwrap();
    if num <= 1 {
        // println!("Returning...");
        return One::one();
    }

    stacker::maybe_grow(1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024, || {
        current * factorial(num - 1)
    })
}

fn main() {
    let num: u64 = 100000;
    println!("Factorial {}! = {}", num, factorial(num));
}
```

I have commented out the debug `println`s.. you can uncomment them if you like.

Comment: `maybe_grow(1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024` will allocate a new stack frame every call. I [measure](http://superuser.com/a/767491/57579) 1GB memory usage. If I change it into `maybe_grow(32 * 1024, 1024 * 1024`, it will not allocate a new stack until 32K is left. Now it uses just 20MB memory. That change does not really change the speed though.

Comment: Ah yes sorry - I did originally have it at a 64k boundary but bumped it up on my final test.

Comment: You say `I do not recommend`, but I think this is really a good option if you can't rewrite a recursive algorithm into an iterative algorithm. A runtime stack overflow is really bad. Of course the algorithm in this question is easy to write iterative.